# Multiple SAM templates on one local emulator

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Is there a way to deploy multiple SAM templates to one emulator.

If I have multiple teams working on their own lambda stacks, each having a SAM template. I would like to be able to run a bigger composite application which may need to call any one of these lambdas but without having to start a local emulator container for each of the lambdas.

```
# I'd like to start one client
 lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',
                                 region_name="us-west-2",
                                 endpoint_url="http://127.0.0.1:3001",
                                 use_ssl=False,
                                 verify=False,
                                 config=botocore.client.Config(
                                     signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED,
                                     retries={'max_attempts': 0},
                                 )
                                 )

# then call each of the lambdas by name 
response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="LambdaApp",
        Payload=bytes(json.dumps(event), encoding='utf8')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check SAM nested template which actually does the something like this.
[for more:](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-nested-applications-for-aws-sam-and-the-aws-serverless-application-repository/)

Comment: Actually I found that for now you can't do nested templates (or applications) with SAM local emulator https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1271

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but now that is possible as per the GitHub link you shard @HIT_girl